# How to configure nginx to give existing static files but forward requests for nonexistent files to apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I supposed to write something like this

```
    location !-f {
        proxy_pass         http://lst207.b.ls1.ru:8000/;
        }

# static content
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|ico|rar|gz|zip|pdf|tar|bmp|xls|doc|swf|mp3|avi|png|htc|txt|htc|flv)$ {
    #root         "$document_root$";
    access_log   off;
    expires      7d;
}
```

But seem "-f" flag doesn't work

Comment: I just thought may be error_page   404  =  /index.php; could help me. if it doesn't send 404 header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try_files is designed for just this scenario.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|ico|rar|gz|zip|pdf|tar|bmp|xls|doc|swf|mp3|avi|png|htc|txt|htc|flv)$ {
    access_log   off;
    expires      7d;
} 

location @fallback {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://lst207.b.ls1.ru:8000/;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. a little remark proxy_pass http://lst207.b.ls1.ru:8000;  - without a slash at the ending. and I don't know why but it doesn't work for me though it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the first line of your index.php (in the comment) is: 
`header("HTTP/1.0 302 Found");` then it should send a 302 instead of a 404 to the browser, but I'm thinking in apache terms, rather than nginx.

The second line could be something like: 
    `header("Location: <redirect location>");`

Might that be enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|ico|rar|gz|zip|pdf|tar|bmp|xls|doc|swf|mp3|avi|png|htc|txt|htc|flv)$ {
    root /the/location/of/static;
    access_log off;
    expires 7d;
    }
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://lst207.b.ls1.ru:8000/;
    }
```

Does this work for you???

Comment: A location does not require the file to exist, so that won't work.

Comment: Ahhhh.. for what reason is this required ???
i mean serve your dynamic content from apache and static from nginx
or
Why not just use the caching that nginx provides...or varnish..???
it seems kind of indirect for your problem..